# How to match a table with 3 columns, returning the first ocurrence of the second column with the first non-value of the third one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm strugling to make this work. I have a table with this structure:

```
enter code here
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      source         |   updated_date   |   closed_date    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        RMD          |   2019-01-01     |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        RMD          |   2019-01-25     |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        RMD          |   2019-01-29     |    2019-02-05    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        SRC          |   2019-02-15     |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        SRC          |   2019-02-19     |    2019-02-21    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        SRC          |   2019-02-20     |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        SRC          |   2019-02-27     |    2019-02-28    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I need to return the first updated date and the respective first non-null closed_date.

Example, based on the above's data, I would like to returng this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      source         |   updated_date   |   closed_date    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        RMD          |   2019-01-01     |    2019-02-05    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        SRC          |   2019-02-15     |    2019-02-21    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        SRC          |   2019-02-20     |    2019-02-28    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

This is quite challenging for me and I'm cracking my head on getting this work. The closest I could get was using self-relationship but I couldn't manage to make this work as I just can't get the first value to match with the second one, and I also tried COALESCE but either it does not work for this example or I didn't used well.

Any good soul to give me a light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cumulative window functions and aggregation:

```
select source, min(updated_date), max(closed_date)
from (select t.*,
             count(closed_date) over (partition by source order by updated_date desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by source, grp;
```

The idea is a *reverse* count of `updated_date` to assign a group to the rows.  Then aggregate based on that group.